# How to connect Mysql with logstash?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch, logstash

When I was on windows this file working well but now I must restart my project on Linux and I don't know how can I do it ? bellow see logstash.conf xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
cammand : `./logstash -f longstash.conf`

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string =>"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
    jdbc_user =>"root"
    jdbc_password =>"password"
    jdbc_driver_library =>"/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class =>"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    schedule =>"* * * * *"
    statement =>"SELECT * FROM Pro WHERE last_modificate >:sql_last_value"
    use_column_value =>true
    tracking_column =>last_modificate
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts =>"localhost:9200"
    action=>update
    document_id =>"%{id}"
    doc_as_upsert =>true
    index =>"blog"
    document_type =>"pro"
  }
}
```

And bellow see the error :

```
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs errors to the console
[WARN ] 2019-02-06 16:24:38.441 [LogStash::Runner] multilocal - Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[INFO ] 2019-02-06 16:24:38.495 [LogStash::Runner] runner - Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.6.0"}
[WARN ] 2019-02-06 16:24:58.845 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] elasticsearch - You are using a deprecated config setting "document_type" set in elasticsearch. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future. Document types are being deprecated in Elasticsearch 6.0, and removed entirely in 7.0. You should avoid this feature If you have any questions about this, please visit the #logstash channel on freenode irc. {:name=>"document_type", :plugin=><LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch hosts=>[//localhost:9200], doc_as_upsert=>true, action=>"update", index=>"blog", id=>"0d9b8021264f8db7c25bca76842096f28d088e42d8e84a573b39874bc2c38c19", document_id=>"%{id}", document_type=>"pro", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_0d66fa34-7e13-432a-9405-8084af971c1a", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, workers=>1, manage_template=>true, template_name=>"logstash", template_overwrite=>false, script_type=>"inline", script_lang=>"painless", script_var_name=>"event", scripted_upsert=>false, retry_initial_interval=>2, retry_max_interval=>64, retry_on_conflict=>1, ilm_enabled=>false, ilm_rollover_alias=>"logstash", ilm_pattern=>"{now/d}-000001", ilm_policy=>"logstash-policy", ssl_certificate_verification=>true, sniffing=>false, sniffing_delay=>5, timeout=>60, pool_max=>1000, pool_max_per_route=>100, resurrect_delay=>5, validate_after_inactivity=>10000, http_compression=>false>}
[INFO ] 2019-02-06 16:24:58.963 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] pipeline - Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[INFO ] 2019-02-06 16:25:00.378 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[WARN ] 2019-02-06 16:25:01.241 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[INFO ] 2019-02-06 16:25:02.692 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
[WARN ] 2019-02-06 16:25:02.705 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
[INFO ] 2019-02-06 16:25:02.805 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[INFO ] 2019-02-06 16:25:02.881 [Ruby-0-Thread-5: :1] elasticsearch - Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[INFO ] 2019-02-06 16:25:03.044 [Ruby-0-Thread-5: :1] elasticsearch - Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[INFO ] 2019-02-06 16:25:03.726 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] pipeline - Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x5e9c3d30 run>"}
[INFO ] 2019-02-06 16:25:03.868 [Ruby-0-Thread-1: /usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:6] agent - Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[INFO ] 2019-02-06 16:25:05.345 [Api Webserver] agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
Wed Feb 06 16:26:05 CET 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Wed Feb 06 16:26:06 CET 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
[ERROR] 2019-02-06 16:26:06.396 [Ruby-0-Thread-15: :1] jdbc - Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:error_message=>"Java::JavaSql::SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"}
{ 2014 rufus-scheduler intercepted an error:
  2014   job:
  2014     Rufus::Scheduler::CronJob "* * * * *" {}
  2014   error:
  2014     2014
  2014     Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError
  2014     Java::JavaSql::SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
  2014       com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(com/mysql/jdbc/SQLError.java:965)
  2014       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlIO.java:3973)
  2014       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlIO.java:3909)
  2014       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlIO.java:873)
  2014       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlIO.java:1710)
  2014       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlIO.java:1226)
  2014       com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java:2188)
  2014       com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java:2219)
  2014       com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java:2014)
  2014       com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java:776)
  2014       com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(com/mysql/jdbc/JDBC4Connection.java:47)
  2014       java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java/lang/reflect/Constructor.java:423)
```

Comment: "/usr/share/logstash/data/queue" - change this directory write access.

Comment: thank you but another error is diplayed, see above

Comment: Can you connect locally to the database using credentials from the config file?

Comment: Yes I can, but just when I'm in root@ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

As the error is self explanatory.

```
 2014     Java::JavaSql::SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

kindly check the configuration credentials. On linux have have to go /usr/share/logstash directory then run the following commnad.

```
sudo bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/yourfilename.conf
```